# Working with two .htaccess RewriteRules

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am wanting to redirect from `category.php` to `page.php` using `.htaccess`. After I'm redirecting successfully from index to `category.php` I'm having problem redirect to the `page.php`.

`.htaccess` file :

```bsh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $ !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt\css\js)

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zא-תA-Z_]+) category.php?name=$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zא-תA-Z_]+)/([0-9a-zא-תA-Z_]+)/ page.php?product=$1&categ=$2 [QSA]
```

The HTML code (`category.php`):

```php
<a href="'.str_replace(" ","_",$cval['pages_name_nice']).'/'.str_replace(" ","_",$get_one_pages['pages_name_nice']).'/"><img src="images/item_button.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></a>
```

Comment: thanks Jack for editing